# postfix/sendmail error unknown referring to command line

Tags: linux, email, php, postfix, sendmail

I have a php script under a `wordpress` theme sending emails using the `mail()` function.
I have `postfix`, `dovecot` & `sendmail` installed on the server.
For a long time the script functioned properly without any issues.
Recently mails are not being sent from that script and after a long wide search the only lead I could find as to this error is this `mail.log` error I am getting from the php `mail()` execution:
`postfix/sendmail[7588]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option`
Couldn't find any info as how to deal with it....
Can anyone help??

Answer (score 2):

Took me a few days but here's the solution:

It's in the mail section of `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
These configurations need to look like this:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```